# Kendo numeric text box spinners appearing ever after set to false

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendonumerictextbox

In my 'incell' editable grid I set numeric text box in column editor function like as shown below. I've set spinners property to false.

```
editor: function (container, options) {
                            $('<input class="form-control p-t-1 text-right" name="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                                .appendTo(container)
                                .kendoNumericTextBox({
                                    format: "c",
                                    spinners: false
                                });
                        },
```

but filed spinner tooltip text 'Increase value' and 'decrease value' is appearing when I hover over the filed in edit mode.
[image]

What am I missing here?
I am using kendo version: 2015.2.902

This is the generated DOM. looks fine to me but not sure why the issue exists

```
<td style="text-align: right;" class="text-right k-state-border-down k-edit-cell" role="gridcell" id="manageTB_active_cell" data-role="editable" aria-describedby="manageTB_active_cell_tt_active">
<span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox form-control p-t-1 text-right">
<span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default k-expand-padding">
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value form-control p-t-1 text-right k-input k-valid" tabindex="0" title="" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<input class="form-control p-t-1 text-right k-input k-valid" name="Periods[2].Amount" data-bind="value:Periods[2].Amount" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" style="display: none;" type="text" aria-valuenow="350000" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<span class="k-select" style="display: none;">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-link">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" title="Increase value">Increase value</span>
</span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-link">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" title="Decrease value">Decrease value</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Seems `UP` and `DOWN` arrow is not displaying so there displays Increase value and Decrease Value as a title

Comment: I just have tested your case. Seems working for me. Please provide more details on what your code looks like.